# How to connect to Mongodb from outside Kubernetes cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I need to connect to mongodb external of the kubernetes cluster. I dont know how to do it when i search on internet all the time i found all information about how to connect to mongodb inside the K8s cluster . On the other hand, I wouldn't be against it. but for the begining of the project i'must to connect to external mongodb .

Do you know how to do it ? or do you have any information who can help me ??

**deployment.yaml :**

```
  - name: XXXX_CONFIG_API_MONGODB
    value: "mongodb://@IP:27017"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Expose a NodePort service for your MongoDB Pod and then use the Node's public IP as the host.

Comment: Have you managed to connect?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update service not in deployment. It's service related issue.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongod-db-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongod-db
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Note:- "mongod-db" is kubernetes selector that should be same in deployment.

Comment: i've to do something in the deployment.yaml file ?

Comment: no . create service that connect to deployment . check :- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Answer (score 0):

> I need to connect to mongodb external of the kubernetes cluster.

K8s allows a few methods for service to be reachable outside the cluster (namely  `hostNetwork`, `hostPort`, `NodePort` , `LoadBalancer`, `Ingress`)

[This article](http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/) is so far one of the best on topic.

In general you just need to create a service that'll point to your mongodb.

It can be one of (but not limited to):

- **`LoadBalancer`** type:

```
kind: Service 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata: 
  name: mongo 
spec: 
  type: LoadBalancer 
  ports: 
    - port: 27017 
  selector: 
    app: my-mongo-db  # this shall match labels from the Deployment
```

- **`NodePort`** type:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-mongo-db
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - 
      port: 27017
      nodePort: 30001 # al the incoming connections to NodeIP:30001 will be forwarded to your mongo-pod
```

There are more ways to achieve that (just don't want to copy paste here that article I have been referring to).

Hope that helps.